# Struggling with Material UI styling solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to be able to inject my own CSS into Material UI's components addition to their other built-in rules, but I'm not sure how I would set these parameters using the styled-components API. Is it even possible?

**snippet**

```
const Wrap = styled(Container)({
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    maxWidth: 'xl',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [styled-components](/questions/tagged/styled-components) and [material-ui](/questions/tagged/material-ui) together. But since you're using Material-UI, you can use its own [styled API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api) instead to better integrate with the Material-UI framework like injecting Material-UI customized theme easily when needed for example.

```js
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { styled as muiStyled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const MyButton1 = styled(Button)({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px"
});
const MyButton2 = muiStyled(Button)((props) => ({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: props.theme.spacing(5)
}));
```

### Usage

```js
<MyButton1>Styled with styled-components API</MyButton1>
<MyButton2>Styled with MUI styled API</MyButton2>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64180977/struggling-with-material-ui-styling-solution]

Answer (score 0):

Your complete js should look more like this. I didnt see any other code so let me know if you need any other questions answered..

Working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kqdo2

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';


function styled(Component) {
  return (style, options) => {
    function StyledComponent(props) {
      const { classes, className, ...other } = props;
      return <Component className={classNames(classes.root, className)} {...other} />;
    }
    StyledComponent.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      className: PropTypes.string,
    };
    const styles =
      typeof style === 'function' ? theme => ({ root: style(theme) }) : { root: style };
    return withStyles(styles, options)(StyledComponent);
  };
}


const Wrap = styled(Container)({
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  maxWidth: 'xl',
});

function StyledComponents() {
  return <Wrap>{'Styled Components'}</Wrap>;
}

export default StyledComponents;
```

Comment: Why not just use [styled API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api)?